# how to find php.ini file in laravel for configuration

Tags: laravel

I get this error

```
mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

How can solve it
I dont know how to find php.ini file in laravel

Comment: I don't why the php.ini is relevant here. Mailing is configured via `config/mail.php` and all relevant `.env` entries are mentioned there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command on your console

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

It will return the path of your php.ini file.

Comment: grep is not recognized command

Comment: What is your OS?. If you're running ubuntu, run
       sudo apt-get install grep